# Best usecases to share Linux user ID among multiple android applications

Tags: android, performance, android-activity

What are the best usecases to share a Linux user ID among multiple android application? can you name few type of application that can benefit form it

I was just experimenting with `android:sharedUserID` but not able to think of what types of application are using this feature. As there are other popular ways available to exchange data among applications.

Comment: Questions which can have a variety of answers aren't really a good fit for the format of this site.